# Unknown Hash of Hashes of Hashes

Tags: perl, reference, hashmap, dereference

i can fetch data from a Database with the following perl code:

```
my %hash = $vars->getVarHash;   #load data into a hash
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

The output of the Dumper looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x55948e0b06b0)' => undef
        };
```

Now i know that this hash points to a hash of variables, and each of them points to a list of options for each variable (i guess a "hash of hashes"), sth like this:

```
HASH(0x55948e0b06b0) --> Variable_a --> Option_a_1, Option_a_2 ...
                     --> Variable_b --> Option_b_1, Option_b_2 ...
                     --> Variable_c --> ...
```

**How do i correctly dereference this hash so i can get the values of the Variables and each of is Options?**

Comment: Seems like the hash `%hash` is undefined: `'HASH(0x55948e0b06b0)' => undef`

Comment: Look at the documentation of ` $vars->getVarHash` - it returns a hash reference, not a hash. Use `my $hash =  $vars->getVarHash; print Dumper $hash;` instead.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`. You should've gotten a warning for that hash assignment.

Comment: thanks for your help, very solid answers here, you guys solved my problem. sadly dont have the reputation to upvote yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic problem is that you can only dereference references. A hash is not a reference, so "dereference a hash" doesn't make sense.

Your dumper output,

```
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x55948e0b06b0)' => undef
        };
```

doesn't show a nested data structure or reference or anything. It's literally a one-element hash whose (single) key is the string `"HASH(0x55948e0b06b0)"` and whose value is `undef`. There's nothing you can do with this structure.

What probably happened is that `getVarHash` returns a reference to a hash (a single value), which (by assigning to a hash) you've implicitly converted to a key whose corresponding value is `undef`. Hash keys are always strings, so the original reference value was lost.

Perl can tell you about this particular problem. You should always start your Perl files with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

The warning for this particular mistake is

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at foo.pl line 123.
```

---

The solution is to store the returned reference in a scalar variable:

```
my $hash = $vars->getVarHash;
print Dumper($hash);
```

Then you can use all the usual methods (as described in e.g. [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut#Using-References)) to dereference it and access its contents, such as `keys %$hash`, `$hash->{$key}`, etc.

Comment: thank you very much, thats a great answer. sadly, i dont have the reputation to upvote yet. this prints out the entire hash, which seems to be a hash of hashes of hashes, now i only have to figure out how to store the values of the "most inner" hash in arrays, but even for that you already gave me a link.

Comment: i changed the title of the question since you said that dereferencing makes no sense here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where `getVarHash()` is defined, but (as others have said) it looks like it returns a hash reference, not a hash as you're assuming.

You could store the returned hash reference in a scalar and use it as a reference:

```
my $hash = $vars->getVarHash;
print Dumper($hash);
```

That's probably the best approach, but it has one disadvantage. If you have code that accesses your hash:

```
say $hash{foo}; # or whatever
```

Then you'll need to rewrite it to use a hash reference instead:

```
say $hash->{foo}; # or whatever
```

An alternative approach is to dereference the value that comes back from the method so that you can use it as a hash.

```
my %hash = %{ $vars->getVarHash };
```

That way, the rest of your code will work as expected without making changes.

Comment: thank you very much, great answer, sadly i dont have the reputation to upvote yet.